# Программно изменить примечание к заказу в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно при создании заказа Woocommerce перезаписать значение поля "комментарий к заказу". Это не меняет информацию в заказе, в чем может быть проблема?

```
  add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation','my_add_fields_contact');
function my_add_fields_contact($data){
    $data['order_comments'] .= ' ' . $data['billing_data_'] . ', ' . $data['billing_time_'];
    file_put_contents('debug_log_1.html', print_r($data, 1));
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В использованном вами хуке передаются данные со страницы checkout, а вам надо добавить комментарий в заказ. Кроме того, этот хук - не фильтр, а акция, что-либо возвращать по return бесполезно.

После создания заказа и сохранения его в базе срабатывает событие `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`. Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 2);
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id, $data ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $note = $data['order_comments'] . ' ' . $data['billing_data_'] . ', ' . $data['billing_time_'];
    $order->add_order_note( $note );
}
```

Добавление информации в заказ производится методом `add_order_note()`. До сохранения заказа в базе этот метод не работает.